# Vaciar propiedades de un objeto tipo polilinea?

Tags: javascript, object, objeto, google-maps-v3

Vaciar propiedades de un objeto tipo polilyne

Necesito vaciar un objeto tipo polilyne para que pueda ser reutilizado las veces que se necesite, quiero que las propiedades quedan vacias, por ejemplo el objeto cuando tienes valores tiene algo asi

```
linea = {
ruta: [coor1, coor2, coor3],
origen: cdmx,
destino: colima

}
```

Lo que quiero es vaciar ese objeto y que me quede de este modo:

```
linea = {
camino: [],
origen
destino
}
```

Estoy usando javascript y la api javascript de google maps version 3.
La forma setMap(null),no me sirve ya que solo oculta la linea pero el objeto sigue estando ahí con sus valores asignados.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta creando un metodo dentro del objeto que limpie las propiedades del mismo:

```
var linea = {
    ruta: [coor1, coor2, coor3],
    origen: cdmx,
    destino: colima,
    clear:function()
    {
        this.ruta = [];
        this.origen = "";
        this.destino = ""   
    }
}
```

Entonces solo tendrias que llamar el metodo cleary limpiara el contenido:

```
linea.clear();
```

Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
var linea = {
  ruta: [33, 44, 55],
  origen: 22,
  destino: 33,
  clear:function()
  {
    this.ruta = [];
    this.origen = "";
    this.destino = "" 
  }
};

linea.clear();

console.log(linea);

linea.ruta.push(3);
linea.ruta.push(55);

console.log(linea);
linea.clear();
console.log(linea);
```

Aunque personalmente no veo problemas con crear un nuevo objeto ya que el GC se encargaria de eliminar la ultima referencia.

Answer (score 0):

puedes acceder a sus atributos, asignarles valores independientemente

para acceder a sus atributos haces referencia con el punto seguido del atributo que quieras obtener.

```js
var linea = {
camino: [1,2,4],
origen:'',
destino:''
};
console.log(linea);

linea.camino=[];

console.log(linea);
```